# pip install from requirements ignores library fork

Tags: python, pip

I added fork of library (sqlalchemy) and another library (alembic), depended on fork source, to requirements.txt. During installation fork and source have  installed.
Why does it happens? Can fork be installed as dependency?

Here is installation process and its results:

```
➜  ~ mkdir test_reqs
➜  ~ cd test_reqs 
➜  test_reqs echo "alembic==0.9.3 
-e git+https://github.com/aCLr/sqlalchemy.git#egg=rel_1_bind_url_as_key" > reqs.txt
➜  test_reqs virtualenv2 venv     
New python executable in /home/anton/test_reqs/venv/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/anton/test_reqs/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
➜  test_reqs source venv/bin/activate
(venv) ➜  test_reqs pip install -r reqs.txt 
Collecting alembic==0.9.3 (from -r reqs.txt (line 1))
Obtaining rel_1_bind_url_as_key from git+https://github.com/aCLr/sqlalchemy.git#egg=rel_1_bind_url_as_key (from -r reqs.txt (line 2))
  Cloning https://github.com/aCLr/sqlalchemy.git to ./venv/src/rel-1-bind-url-as-key
  Running setup.py (path:/home/anton/test_reqs/venv/src/rel-1-bind-url-as-key/setup.py) egg_info for package rel-1-bind-url-as-key produced metadata for project name sqlalchemy. Fix your #egg=rel-1-bind-url-as-key fragments.
Collecting SQLAlchemy>=0.7.6 (from alembic==0.9.3->-r reqs.txt (line 1))
Collecting Mako (from alembic==0.9.3->-r reqs.txt (line 1))
Collecting python-editor>=0.3 (from alembic==0.9.3->-r reqs.txt (line 1))
Collecting python-dateutil (from alembic==0.9.3->-r reqs.txt (line 1))
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.9.2 (from Mako->alembic==0.9.3->-r reqs.txt (line 1))
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil->alembic==0.9.3->-r reqs.txt (line 1))
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy, MarkupSafe, Mako, python-editor, six, python-dateutil, alembic, sqlalchemy
  Running setup.py develop for sqlalchemy
Successfully installed Mako-1.0.7 MarkupSafe-1.0 SQLAlchemy-1.1.15 alembic-0.9.3 python-dateutil-2.6.1 python-editor-1.0.3 six-1.11.0 sqlalchemy-1.1.15
(venv) ➜  test_reqs pip list|grep -i sqlalchemy
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
SQLAlchemy (1.1.15, /home/anton/test_reqs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages)
(venv) ➜  test_reqs pip uninstall sqlalchemy
Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-1.1.15:
...
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-1.1.15
(venv) ➜  test_reqs pip uninstall sqlalchemy
Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-1.0.20.dev0:
  /home/anton/test_reqs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy.egg-link
Proceed (y/n)? ^COperation cancelled by user
(venv) ➜  test_reqs pip list|grep -i sqlalchemy
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
SQLAlchemy (1.0.20.dev0, /home/anton/test_reqs/venv/src/rel-1-bind-url-as-key/lib)
(venv) ➜  test_reqs pip uninstall sqlalchemy   
Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-1.0.20.dev0:
  /home/anton/test_reqs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy.egg-link
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-1.0.20.dev0
(venv) ➜  test_reqs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-e` is extra, without it everything works fine :)